# change the Input Name based on the multiple dropdown selection in html form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am trying to create add/remove form fields dynamically with jQuery where the user can submit multiple queries based on the dropdown selections. At the end, it should generate URL with a combination of selection.So far I have managed to create add/remove form fields with the option of multiple queries.

For example, if the user submits input for a car then it will generate URL like:

`exmaple.com/?car=xxx`

and which is working.

If a user submits input for car and bike then it should generate:

```
exmaple.com/?car=xxx&bike=yyy
```

but it is generating like:

```
exmaple.com/?car=xxx&car=yyy
```

So how can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.addmore = function(options) {
    var moreElement = this,
      singlePreSelectedValue = '',
      selectedValue = [],
      defaultOption = {
        addText: 'add more',
        removeText: 'Remote',
        selectBoxDuplicate: true,
        avoidDuplicationSelection: function(e) {
          var o = e;
          if ($.inArray($(o).val(), selectedValue) != -1) {
            $(o).val(singlePreSelectedValue);
            alert('Value already selected.');
          } else {
            var hasSelectValue = true;
            $.each($('.removeDuplication'), function(i, v) {
              if ($(this).val() == 'select') {
                hasSelectValue = false;
                return false;
              }

            });

          }
        },
        prevSelectedValue: function(e) {
          var o = e;
          selectedValue = [];
          $.each($('.removeDuplication'), function(i, v) {
            if ($(this).val() != 'select') {
              selectedValue.push($(this).val());
            }
          });
          singlePreSelectedValue = $(o).val();
        }
      }
    defaultOption = $.extend(true, defaultOption, options);

    /*        $(this).find('select').prepend('<option value="select" selected>Select</option>');*/
    $(moreElement).after('<a href="javascript:void(0)" data-id="more">' + defaultOption.addText + '</a>');
    $('[data-id="more"]').click(function() {
      var dataMore = this,
        removeDuplication = [];
      $(dataMore).before($(moreElement).clone().find('input').not('input[type="submit"]').val('').end().end().find('select.removeDuplication').focus(function() {
        if (!defaultOption.selectBoxDuplicate) {
          defaultOption.prevSelectedValue(this);
        }
      }).change(function() {
        if (!defaultOption.selectBoxDuplicate) {
          defaultOption.avoidDuplicationSelection(this);
        }
      }).end().append(function() {
        return $('<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="circular deleteCons icon icon-functional button" data-id="remove"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> ' + +'</a>').click(function() {
          $(this).parent().remove();
        });
      }));
      if (!defaultOption.selectBoxDuplicate) {
        $.each($('.removeDuplication'), function(i, v) {
          if ($(this).val() != 'select') {
            removeDuplication.push($(this).val());
          }
        });
        $.each(removeDuplication, function(i, v) {
          $('.removeDuplication').last().find('option[value="' + removeDuplication[i] + '"]').remove();
        });
      }
    });
    $('.removeDuplication').focus(function(e) {
      defaultOption.prevSelectedValue(this);
    }).change(function() {
      defaultOption.avoidDuplicationSelection(this);
    });
    return this;
  }

  $('dl').addmore({
    addText: 'Add',
    removeText: 'Remove',
    selectBoxDuplicate: false
  });
});




$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    var str = $(this).val();
    $("#searchtermid").attr("name", str);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form class="navbar-form" action="" method="get" action="demo_form.asp">
  <dl>
    <select class="removeDuplication">
   <option value="car">Car</option>
   <option value="bike">Bike</option>
   <option value="plane">Plane</option>
  </select>
    <textarea class="form-control custom-control" name="car" id="searchtermid" placeholder="Search term" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" rows="3" style="resize:none" required></textarea>
  </dl>
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

After getting input from ***Standard Quality***, I have modified my scripts and html. 
https://jsfiddle.net/paul85/wjhqszmg/

But still is not letting the user submit input form. Most important, when user will submit from it should redirect to a page for correctly generated URL.
If user submit input for car and bike then redirecting page address or URL will be:

```
exmaple.com/?car=xxx&bike=yyy
```

**HTML**

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form id="main-form" class="navbar-form" action="/results.html" method="get">
  <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <div class="form-field">
        <select class="removeDuplication">
          <option value="car" >Car</option>
          <option value="bike">Bike</option>
          <option value="plane">Plane</option>
        </select>
        <textarea class="form-control custom-control" name="car" id="searchtermid" placeholder="Search term" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>
      </div>
  </div>
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <input class ="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 3; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
    var form = $('#main-form');
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-field">\
                                <select class="removeDuplication">\
                                    <option value=""></option>\
                                    <option value="car">Car</option>\
                                    <option value="bike">Bike</option>\
                                    <option value="plane">Plane</option>\
                                </select>\
                                <textarea class="form-control custom-control" name="car" id="searchtermid" placeholder="Search term" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" rows="3" style="resize:none"></textarea>\
                                <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>\
                                </div>'); //add input box
        } else {
        alert("Sorry, you have reached maximum add options.");
      }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });

    $(document).on('change','select.removeDuplication',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cI = $(this);
        var others=$('select.removeDuplication').not(cI);
        $.each(others,function(){
            if($(cI).val()==$(this).val() && $(cI).val()!="") {
                $(cI).val('');
                alert($(this).val()+' already selected.');
            }
        });
    });
  /*$(form).submit(function(e){*/
    form.on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var queries = [];
        var slectedall=true;
        var fillupfield=true;
        form.find('.form-field').each(function(index, field) {
            var query = {};
            query.type = $(field).find('select').val();
            query.value = $(field).find('textarea').val();
            if (query.type !=""){
                queries.push(query);
            } else{
                slectedall=false;
            }
        });

        for (i = 0; i < queries.length; i += 1) {
            var query = queries[i];
            if (query.value.trim() ===""){
                fillupfield=false;
            }       
        };
        if (slectedall===false){
            alert('Please select option.');
        } else {
            if (fillupfield===false){
                alert('Please insert your searchterm.');
            } else {
          $("form").submit();
            }

        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're extending jQuery, which isn't necessary for this, and is contributing to making the code much less legible. To be honest, I haven't even dug through it to find the problem -- instead, I wrote something from scratch. StackOverflow snippets don't allow forms, so here's a working JSBin: http://jsbin.com/gokodaluna/edit?html,js,output

(Note that I've changed your HTML markup a little bit)

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<form id="main-form" class="navbar-form" action="" method="get" action="demo_form.asp">
  <div class="fields">
    <div class="form-field">
      <select class="removeDuplication">
        <option value="car">Car</option>
        <option value="bike">Bike</option>
        <option value="plane">Plane</option>
      </select>
      <textarea class="form-control custom-control" name="car" id="searchtermid" placeholder="Search term" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" rows="3" style="resize:none" required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <input class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" value="Add" id="form-add">
  <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<h2 id="final-url"></h2>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
/* Save your initial variables */
var form = $('#main-form');
var formFields = form.find('.fields')
var addButton = $('#form-add');
var emptyInput = $('.form-field').clone(); // clone this at initialization so we always have an empty field
var finalUrl = $("#final-url");

addButton.on('click', function() {
  emptyInput.clone().appendTo(formFields);
  /* clone this again so our initial field is always empty and available */
})

form.on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  var queries = [];
  form.find('.form-field').each(function(index, field) {
    var query = {};
    query.type = $(field).find('select').val();
    query.value = $(field).find('textarea').val();
    queries.push(query);
  });
  var url = window.location.href;
  for (i = 0; i < queries.length; i += 1) {
    var query = queries[i];
    var ampOrQ = (i === 0) ? "?" : "&";
    url += ampOrQ + query.type + "=" + query.value;
  }

  /* print the URL into the dom if you want to see it working */
  finalUrl.text(url);

  /* or forward users to the new URL you've generated */
  window.location.href = url;

})
```

**Edit:** in the revised code in your question, you're calling `$("form").submit()` in that if-else statement. When you trigger this, the larger function is still catching the `submit` event, so it's immediately running `e.preventDefault()` again. If you need to simply forward the user to the new URL, just set it with `window.location.href =`. See the last few lines of my (edited) code above.

Comment: thanks for your code and feedback. But still it didn't solve my problem. I have updated my problem again with your code.